# Making a clustered graphviz graph look more tree-like

Tags: tree, graphviz

I have the following Graphviz:

```
graph {
    node[width = 0.6, height = 0.6, fixedsize=true, shape=circle];
    nodesep = 0.5;
    a[label="22"];
    b[label="22"];
    c[label="34"];
    d[label="22"];
    e[label="99"];
    f[label="34"];
    g[label="40"];
    h[label="37"];
    i[label="22"];
    j[label="99"];
    k[label="135"];
    l[label="129"];
    m[label="40"];
    edge[penwidth=1.0]; //principal path edges
    a -- b;
    b -- d;
    c -- f;
    d -- i;
    e -- j;
    g -- m;
    edge[penwidth=1.0]; //other edges
    a -- c;
    b -- e;
    c -- g;
    d -- h;
    e -- k;
    g -- l;
}
```

This draws me a nice, tree-shaped graph:
[image: tree shaped graph]

Then, I wanted to change up a few things (in particular, 'drawing around' paths with matching values), so I did this, [following this example](http://graphviz.org/content/cluster):

```
graph {
    node[width = 0.6, height = 0.6, fixedsize=true, shape=circle];
    nodesep = 0.5;
    subgraph cluster_0 {
             style = rounded;
             a[label="22"];
             b[label="22"];
             d[label="22"];
             i[label="22"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_1 {
             style = rounded;            
             c[label="34"];
             f[shape=diamond, label="34"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_2 {
             style = rounded;
             e[label="99"];
             j[shape=diamond,label="99"]; 
    }
    subgraph cluster_3 {
             style = rounded;
             g[label="40"];
             m[shape=diamond, label="40"];
    }
    node[shape = diamond];
    h[shape=diamond, label="37"];
    k[label="135"];
    l[label="129"];
    edge[penwidth=1.0]; //principal path edges
    a -- b;
    b -- d;
    c -- f;
    d -- i;
    e -- j;
    g -- m;
    edge[penwidth=3.0]; //other edges
    a -- c;
    b -- e;
    c -- g;
    d -- h;
    e -- k;
    g -- l;
}
```

However, the end result has each cluster vertical, which doesn't look especially tree-like:
[image: vertical clusters]

Is there a way to make the second graph look more like the first?

Comment: If that helps {rank=same; a b d i} will place vertices on the same level and horizontal.

Comment: No. Clusters are rectangular subgraphs. The vertical position (rank) inside a cluster is fixed. Horizontal position is affected by edges to external nodes.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you need to keep the visible border around the cluster and double-sided branches, maybe even with the arrangement of nodes on a diagonal inside the cluster. In [`dot`](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/dot/) layout engine, you can make a diagonal of nodes using invisible nodes and edges, but if extra nodes are not desired, then try [`fdp`](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/fdp/) or [`osage`](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/osage/) layout engines, since they keep the border around the cluster visible.

The `osage` engine is more for rectangular areas and not good for trees ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPJim.png)), so I tried `fdp`. With [`K=.5`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/K/) and [`start=5`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/start/) attributes and by assigning explicit positions to nodes with [`pos`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/pos/) I got something similar to a tree, I think if I tried changing this values, it might work better.
Script:

```
graph {
    layout=fdp
    K=.5
    start=5
    
    node[width = 0.6, height = 0.6, fixedsize=true, shape=circle];
    nodesep = .5;
    subgraph cluster_0 {
             style = rounded;
             a[label="22" pos="0,0!"];
             b[label="22" pos="-1,-1!"];
             d[label="22" pos="-2,-2!"];
             i[label="22" pos="-3,-3!"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_1 {
             style = rounded;            
             c[label="34" pos="1,-1!"];
             f[shape=diamond, label="34" pos="1,-2!"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_2 {
             style = rounded;
             e[label="99" pos="2,-2!"];
             j[shape=diamond,label="99" pos="2,-3!"]; 
    }
    subgraph cluster_3 {
             style = rounded;
             g[label="40" pos="3,-2!"];
             m[shape=diamond, label="40" pos="3,-3!"];
    }
    node[shape = diamond];
    h[shape=diamond, label="37"];
    k[label="135"];
    l[label="129"];
    edge[penwidth=1.0]; //principal path edges
    a -- b;
    b -- d;
    c -- f;
    d -- i;
    e -- j;
    g -- m;
    edge[penwidth=3.0]; //other edges
    a -- c;
    b -- e;
    c -- g;
    d -- h;
    e -- k;
    g -- l;
}
```

Result:
[image: clustered graph looks tree-like made with graphviz fdp]